# Molifier of a function in any domain

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\Omega\times(0,T))$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a open and connected subset (may be unbounded) and $T>0$ is a real number. For $h>0$ and $(x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T)$, let us define the molification of $f$ by $f_h$ as below:
$$
f_h(x,t)=\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{t}e^\frac{s-t}{h}f(x,s)\,ds.
$$
Then $f_h\to f$ in the norm of $L^p(\Omega\times(0,T))$ as $h\to 0$.

I have seen this result in (i) of Lemma 2.9 in the article: [https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/papers/annali1.pdf](https://math.aalto.fi/%7Ejkkinnun/papers/annali1.pdf)

But it is without proof mentioned that it is straightforward. Can someone please help with the same?

Thanks in advance.